# Print to printer from a jsp page. Using a button to retrieve data from a database and printing

Tags: java, jsp, printing, mssql-jdbc

I'm creating this jsp page whereby I'm going to retrieve values from a database and send it to print on the printer. Like physical printers that print papers.

For example the table employee has name, id, age, position, etc. I'm going to retrieve the name and id and print it to the printer using jsp. How do i do this?

I would just like to know the command to use in jsp, when I want to click a button and then make it retrieve all the date I have choose and print.

Like for example

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
         <th>Emp ID</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Age</th>
    </tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
    <tr>
         <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
         <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
         <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
         <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I know this much but the thing is i don't know how to use the printer function for JSP and some help is greatly appreciated! I would like to be able to choose the row that i want and print that row through a printer. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP is a mechanism for generating HTML pages. These pages are designed to be viewed in a browser. So, to get the browser to print the resulting HTML page, you would need to insert some JavaScript at the bottom of the page such as:

```
<script>
    window.print();
</script>
```

This script would then request the browser to print the entire page. If you need a subset of this printed, then you may need to generate another page containing just the information you want and the script above to request that the browser prints it.

EDIT

Basically, you need a web browser to make all this work. Your main page (JSP) will show a list of all records, each record is a link to a page (JSP) that just shows the one record and has the print script built it (or a print button to allow the user to kick it off manually).

Comment: Wonderful! Just what i am looking for. So basically i have to create another page containing the information retrieved from the database that i want to print and then execute this script from this page. Is what i understand from your answer correct? Could you explain to me how do i go about doing that? Or is there any site or anything that i can refer to because i don't know what this process/method is called else i can try my best "google-ing" it haha. Thank you so much for your help jason!